# How to [Filter] data by {Array formula}?

Tags: arrays, excel

My Sheet1! looks like -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeEOZ.jpg

On Sheet2! i want to import all rows belongs to Nov-13. Similarly on Sheet3! all rows belongs to Dec-13 ... How to do such dynamic filter using array formula?? I need array as my data source is a form & new rows will be added everyday. I want to do that by formula not using spreadsheets 'Filter" option.

My expected results for sheet2! will look like-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/faHAq.jpg

Comment: Filtering the data on Month and copy-pasting unique values should work for you. Basic spreadsheet function.

Comment: I want array to do it automatically. Manually copy-paste is not suitable as sheet is linked to a form and new data will be submitted every day. If i do copy-paste I need to copy-paste daily for each new rows, right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem, you need to use a field to *filter* the date (eg. **Sheet1!E1**).

Assuming your tables start on A1 in both sheets you could insert:

`=IF(Sheet1!$E$2=Sheet1!$A2;Sheet1!A2;"")` in column A-C in your Sheet2 and down till your max. entries.

So you can specify your desired Date in **Sheet1!E1** and all your entries should appear in Sheet2

Answer (score 0):

Just because you asked for an Array Function, here is what you need to do.

1- In Sheet2, Enter the month in A1 (say Nov-13)
2- Then in Sheet2->A2 enter the following Array function. Note `Monthly Data` is sheet one where you have the full table.

[function]

```
{=IF(ISERROR(
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)),
"",
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,1))}
```

3- Drag and fill in Column A till you see a blank cell

[image]

4- Then you need to modify the same function for `Division`, i.e., in column B2, enter the following formula

[function]

```
{=IF(ISERROR(
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,2)),
"",
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,2))}
```

5- Drag and fill in Column B till you see a blank cell

6- Repeat the same for `District` column.

[function]

```
{=IF(ISERROR(
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,3)),
"",
INDEX('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$C$13,SMALL(IF('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13=$A$1,ROW('Monthly Data'!$A$2:$A$13)),ROW(1:1))-1,3))}
```

Hope this helps.